# Regular Expression Rewrite Rule Adding Leading Zeros with Same Length

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to rewrite some URLs like seen below in Apache htaccess

```
/xyz-12          ---->       /xyz/000012
/xyz-123         ---->       /xyz/000123
/xyz-1234        ---->       /xyz/001234
/xyz-12345       ---->       /xyz/012345
/xyz-123456      ---->       /xyz/123456
```

As seen I keep digit number same.

Can be written in one Rewrite Rule?

tHanks.

Comment: It's a special format of ID which is prefixed with other codes. Sample in question is very simple to make it easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a direct option to somehow format numbers in an apache RewriteRule. Maybe there is some module providing that out in the depth of the internet. But you certainly can do the following with a plain rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?xyz-(\d{2})$ /xyz/0000$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?xyz-(\d{3})$ /xyz/000$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?xyz-(\d{4})$ /xyz/00$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?xyz-(\d{5})$ /xyz/0$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?xyz-(\d{6})$ /xyz/$1 [L]
```

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this solution is the easiest way to write it. In fact, I want to know that is it possible to code a dynamic regex to handle all in one.

Comment: A regular expression is used to match a subject, not to manipulate it.